# Expand the submenu to the opposite direction when close to the edge of the window

Tags: jquery, css

I have a simple submenu using css, the structure is an unordered list, and it shows up on hover state by changing the display to "block".

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">item with submenu</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the css:

```
.submenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

ul li:hover>ul.submenu {
    display: block;
}
```

You can see an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y2vgj/

And here:
http://tinkerbin.com/9TXjbi8c

(Its the same in both links)

Now, what im trying to do, is to expand the sub menu to the other direction when the page is too small to show it entirely. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Honestly I think you're better off making a separate class and applying it to the menus on the right side to keep them inside the container regardless of size rather than worrying about page size.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following styles for submenu li.

```
.submenu li {
    float: none;
    width: 150px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

Adjust margin and width for putting them in proper position.
The above change will show them horizontally.